# Django Update serializer and unique constainst

Tags: python, django, database, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a meal planner with react and django. I am having issues with the form and getting it to the backend. Right now I can submit the form from react and I get the data back to django correctly. Unless I need to add another mealItem for the same date and serviceType ('lunch', 'dinner'). I get the unique constraint error for the following fields: "meals_meal.menu_id, meals_meal.date, meals_meal.type, meals_meal.url".

I have an update function in the serializer that is not being called. What can I do to check for date and type if they exist update the data.

I need the lunch and dinners to be seperate even if they are from the same date.

Models.py

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(
        Menu,
        related_name='meals',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    type = models.CharField(
        choices=[
            ('lunch', 'Lunch'),
            ('dinner', 'Dinner'),
        ],
        max_length=10,
    )
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200, default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        editable=False,
    )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        editable=False,
    )
    objects = MealQuerySet.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['menu', 'date', 'type', 'url']
        ordering = ['date', '-type']


class MealItem(models.Model):
    meal = models.ForeignKey(
        Meal,
        related_name='items',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(
        choices=[
            ('entre', 'Entre'),
            ('side', 'Side'),
            ('other', 'Other'),
        ],
        max_length=10,
    )
    is_dairy_free = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        verbose_name='D',
        help_text='Dairy Free',
    )
    is_gluten_free = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        verbose_name='G',
        help_text='Gluten Free',
    )
    is_vegetarian = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        verbose_name='V',
        help_text='Vegetarian',
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        editable=False,
    )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        editable=False,
    )
```

Serializers.py

```
class MealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = MealItemSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Meal
        fields = ['id', 'date', 'type','url', 'items', 'menu', ]
        validators = []


    def create(self, validated_data):
        item_data = validated_data.pop('items')
        meal= Meal.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for item_data in item_data:
            MealItem.objects.get_or_create(meal=meal, **item_data)
        return meal
    
    def update(sel, instance, validated_data):
        instance.id = validated_data.get('id', instance.id)
        instance.date = validated_data.get('date', instance.date)
        instance.type = validated_data.get('type', instance.type)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Views.Py

```
class MealViewSet(LoginRequiredMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MealSerializer
    pagination_class = MealPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            queryset = Menu.objects.all()
            menu = get_object_or_404(
                queryset, pk=self.kwargs['menu_pk'], users=self.request.user)
            
            return Meal.objects.filter(menu=menu)
        else:
            print("not auth")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request, "/login")

    def post(self, request, menu_pk):
        data = self.request.data
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated and user.has_perm("meals.change_menu"):
            
            if request.method == "POST":
                serializer =MealSerializer(data=data)
                if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    serializer.save()
                    return Response({'success':"Your post was successfull."})
                return Response({'failure': 'post was not authenticated'})
        return Response({'failure': "user is not authenticated or does not have permission to submit form"})

def update(self, request):
        data = self.request.data
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated and user.has_perm("meals.change_menu"):
            
            if request.method == 'PUT':
                serializer = MealItemSerializer(instance=self.get_object(), data=data, partial=True )
                
                if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    serializer.save()
                    return Response({"Success": "Your meal was updated"})
```

This is the result I need to get. But right now I only submit one meal at a time in the items array. As oppposed to adding all three meals like I do in the django admin add meals pannel.

```
            "id": 1,
            "date": "2021-11-17",
            "type": "lunch",
            "url": "#ImageUrlFromFirebase",
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "milk",
                    "type": "entre",
                    "is_dairy_free": false,
                    "is_gluten_free": false,
                    "is_vegetarian": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "beans",
                    "type": "side",
                    "is_dairy_free": false,
                    "is_gluten_free": true,
                    "is_vegetarian": false
                },
                {
                    "name": "sleep",
                    "type": "other",
                    "is_dairy_free": true,
                    "is_gluten_free": false,
                    "is_vegetarian": false
                }
            ],
            "menu": 1
        },
```

Comment: Kindly add only relevant code , and endpoints that you're calling while creating and updating ,

Comment: There you go, I removed all unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

The update method is called when the request type is `PUT` and corresponding to that there has to be an `update` method on your Viewset, which is missing it seems ? also , if an update is partial (that means only some fields are going to get updated ) then `partial = True` (has to be), for ref https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/

Ideally, I would create another viewset with the name `MealItemViewset` which will then have the `update` method on it , so we can separate `creation, deletion and updating` of `Meals` and `MealItems`

Comment: Would I need to add the get_queryset inside that ```MealItemViewset```? I also change the post function to create, and added a update function to MealViewset. I can look in to creating a new viewset for those. Right now when I use put as the request I get method not allowed. I updated the views to show the update function.